# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^nn\binom{n-1}{k-1} = n2^{n-1} $ ( on basis of $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n$). What is the part I don't understand?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know that on the basis of that equality: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n$

I can prove that those both are true.

$$\sum_{k=0}^nn\binom{n-1}{k-1} = n2^{n-1} $$

$$\sum_{k=0}^nn(n-1)\binom{n-2}{k-2} n(n-1)2^{n-2}$$

But I am not sure how. Let's take the first one:

$$\sum_{k=0}^nn\binom{n-1}{k-1} = n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1} = n\sum_{k=-1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k} = (?) = n2^{n-1} $$

I don't know hat to put in the place of that question mark. I see that the last form is not the one from my basic equality (in the sum, on bottom i got $k=-1$ and that is not equal to $k$).

Comment: More generally $(-N)!=\pm \infty$, where N is a natural number does wonders. This is how ${2 \choose 3}=0$, $ {3 \choose -2}=0$

Answer (score 2):

We assume by convention that $\large n\choose x$ $=0$ whenever $x<0$

Comment: So I can writ that: $n\sum_{k=-1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k} = n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k} = n2^{n-1} $? Why Is that?

Comment: @mathmath after you write it that way, you can use a simple combinatorial argument. Notice that the summation represents the total number of ways of choosing any number of objects from a pool of $n-1$ objects. So every object has two choices: to either be selected or not. Since there are $n-1$ objects, you get $2^{n-1}$

Comment: So it is true that: $n\sum_{k=-10000}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k} = n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k} = n2^{n-1} $?

Comment: @mathmath Yes. Remember that this is just a notation and choosing a negative number of objects from a pool does not mean anything in real life, hence we take that to be $0$.

Comment: Does that process of going down to $0$ with lower limit of sum change upper limit of sum in any way? Because, as I understand the upper limit of sum and number on top of newton's symbol must be equal, to make it possible to transform that into exponential function.

Comment: @mathmath that is specific to the equation and needs to be done so that the sum stays consistent

Comment: But why is that true then? $n \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1} = n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} = n (1+1)^{n-1} = n 2^{n-1}$ Here the lower limit got increased to 0 (as you said), but it changed also the upper limit. It blows my mind.

Comment: @mathmath that's a variable substitution, increasing $k$ to $0$ is only done so that the equation makes sense

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now, just please, correct me if im wrong. We get an expression that represents sum of (among others) some elements that are equal to 0 (with numbers in newton's sybol that are < 0). So, to make it more clear (and cut all the 0es) we simply reduse the lower border and at the same time decrease the total number of elements (because the elements that are equal to 0 were also counted). Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117315/discussion-between-thedumbkid-and-mathmath).

Answer (score 0):

The formula $\;\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n$ stems from the binomial formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k=(1+x)^n, \tag{1}$$
in which we set $x=1$.
Differentiating both sides of this formula, we get
$$n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}x^{k-1},$$
and we can observe that
$$k\binom nk=k\frac{n!}{k!\,(n-k)!}= \frac{n!}{(k-1)!\,(n-k)!}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$$
Can you proceed?